# Check which commit is ahead the origin/master

Tags: git, github

On my **master** branch, when I run `git status`,  I got :

```
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
```

I would like to know what exactly is that commit which is ahead the remote master branch. How to achieve this?

I tried `git log` command, compared my local commitment history with the remote repo commitment history, they look exactly the same....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the double dot annotation to find all commits which are reachable from one reference but not the other.

In your case you could use the following command:

```
git log origin/master..master
```

This effectively tells git to print all commits that are reachable from `master` but not from `origin/master`, so all commits which weren't pushed to the remote.

---

You can read more about the double dot annotation in the [Revision Selection chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) of the gitpro book.
Or in the [official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) about git revisions.